# What is the average width of a given tetrahedron?

Tags: integration, geometry, integral-geometry

I have a tetrahedron with (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2) vertex. What is the average width? I don`t know how to start it. I need to find a useful parameterization. Please help me with any ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by *width* of a $3$D object?

Comment: @Henry it is the average of the width of the projection of the object along all possible directions. see [Mean width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_width) for more detail definition.

Comment: @Bea, I will smooth out the edges of the tetrahedron as thin cylinder, use the relation between the mean width $b$ and mean curvature $H$ for convex body $K$:
$$b(K) = \int_{\partial K} \frac{H}{2\pi} dS$$
to express the average width you want in terms of the edge lengths and dihedral angles of the tetrahedron.

Comment: **Hint:** Why don't you just melt it into a sphere ?

Comment: @Lucian, I don't see how can melting it to a sphere give you the correct answer $$\frac{3}{4\pi}\left[\frac{\pi}{2} + \sqrt{2}\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right] \approx 1.11312749488225$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let us recall some definitions to make sure everyone is on the same page.

Given any compact body $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, the support function of $\mathcal{B}$ along a direction $\hat{n} \in S^2$ is defined as
$$h_{\mathcal{B}}(\hat{n}) = \max\{ \; \hat{n}\cdot\vec{x} : \vec{x} \in \mathcal{B} \}$$
The expression $b_{\mathcal{B}}(\hat{n}) = h_{\mathcal{B}}(\hat{n}) + h_{\mathcal{B}}(-\hat{n})$ is the width of the image of $\mathcal{B}$ under orthogonal projection onto any line parallel to $\hat{n}$. The [mean width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_width) of $\mathcal{B}$ (also known as mean breath or mean caliper diameter) is the average of $b_{\mathcal{B}}(\hat{n})$ for $\hat{n}$ over $S^2$.

$$b(\mathcal{B})\;\stackrel{def}{=}\; \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{S^2} b_{\mathcal{B}}(\hat{n}) d\mu(\hat{n})$$

It is clear $b(\mathcal{B})$ is invariant under translation and rotation of $\mathcal{B}$. To compute the mean width of the tetrahedron at hand (let us call it $\Delta$ ), we can translate it to the standard simplex:

$$\Delta_0 \stackrel{def}{=} \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x, y, z \ge 0 \land x+y+z \le 1 \}$$
If we parametrize $S^2$ using spherical polar coordinates,
$$[0,\pi] \times [-\pi,\pi) \ni (\theta,\phi) \quad\mapsto\quad \hat{n} = (\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta ) \in S^2$$
we have
$$\begin{align}
b(\Delta) = b(\Delta_0) 
&=  \frac{1}{4\pi}
\int_{S^2} \left( h_{\Delta_0}(\hat{n}) + h_{\Delta_0}(-\hat{n})\right) \sin\theta d\theta d\phi\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}
\int_{S^2} h_{\Delta_0}(\hat{n}) \sin\theta d\theta d\phi\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}
\int_{S^2} \max\big\{\; 0, \sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta\;\big\} 
\sin\theta d\theta d\phi\\
&= \frac{3}{2\pi} 
\int_{D}
\cos\theta \sin\theta d\theta d\phi
\end{align}
$$
where $D$ is the region on $S^2$ where $\cos\theta \ge \max\{\; \sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi, 0\;\}$.

Parametrize the upper hemisphere of $S^2$ by 
$$\mathbb{R}^2 \ni ( u, v ) \quad\mapsto\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}} (u, v, 1 ) \in S^2$$
and let $\rho = \sqrt{u^2+v^2} = \tan\theta$, we have

$$\cos\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}\quad\text{ and }\quad
d\mu(\hat{n}) = \sin\theta d\theta d\phi = \frac{\rho d\rho d\phi}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}^3}$$
In terms of $u, v$, the region $D$ above corresponds to the condition $u, v \le 1$.
In terms of $\rho,\phi$, this becomes

$$\rho \le \Lambda(\phi) \quad\text{ where }\quad \Lambda(\phi) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\cos\phi}, & -\frac{\pi}{2} < \phi \le \frac{\pi}{4}\\
\frac{1}{\sin\phi}, &  \frac{\pi}{4} < \phi <   \pi\\
\infty & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

This leads to

$$\begin{align}
b(\Delta) 
&= \frac{3}{2\pi}\int_{u,v \le 1} \frac{\rho d\rho d\phi}{(1+\rho^2)^2}
= \frac{3}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} 
\int_0^{\Lambda(\phi)} \frac{d\rho^2}{(1+\rho^2)^2}  d\phi\\
&= \frac{3}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}
\left[ 1 - \frac{1}{1 + \Lambda(\phi)^2}\right] d\phi
= \frac{3}{2\pi}\left[
\pi - \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos^2\phi}{1 + \cos^2\phi} d\phi \right]
\end{align}
$$
Change variable to $t = \tan\phi$, we get

$$\begin{align}
b(\Delta) 
&= \frac{3}{2\pi}\left[\pi - \int_{-\infty}^1 \frac{dt}{(2+t^2)(1+t^2)}\right]
= \frac{3}{2\pi}\left[
\frac{\pi}{4} + 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\right]\\
&\approx 1.1131274948822501384717878345303502990597\ldots
\end{align}
$$

As one can see from above, it is very tedious to compute the mean width by evaluation of its defining integral. There is a short cut for convex polyhedron.

For any compact convex body $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with smooth enough boundary, there is an interesting formula:
$$b(\mathcal{B}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial \mathcal{B}} H dS\tag{*1}$$
where $H$ and $dS$ is the [mean curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature) and surface element for the boundary $\partial \mathcal{B}$.

Given a convex polyhedron $P$, we cannot directly apply this formula because
$\partial P$ is not smooth enough. To bypass this obstacle, consider the 
[Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of $P$ with $\bar{B}(\epsilon)$, a closed ball centered at $0$ with small radius $\epsilon$.

$$P_{\epsilon} \stackrel{def}{=} P + \bar{B}(\epsilon) = \big\{\; \vec{p} + \vec{q}\;:\; \vec{p} \in P, |\vec{q}| \le \epsilon \;\big\}$$

It is clear $\;b(P_{\epsilon})\;$ = $b(P) + 2\epsilon$. Furthermore, the boundary $\partial P_{\epsilon}$ is now smooth enough. Let $K$ be the 
[Gaussian curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) 
on the boundary. If $V,E,F$ are the number of vertices, edges and faces of $P$, the boundary $\partial P_{\epsilon}$ consists of

- $V$ spherical fragments with radius $\epsilon$, one for each vertex.

  On these spherical fragments, $H = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $K = \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$. Notice $K = 0$ outside these spherical fragments, [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) tell us the total area of these fragments is $4\pi \epsilon^2$. As a result, their contribution to RHS of $(*1)$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{4\pi\epsilon^2}{\epsilon}\right) = 2\epsilon$.
- $E$ cylindrical fragments with radius $\epsilon$, one for each edge.

  For any edge $e$ of $P$, let $\ell_e$ be its length. Let $\psi_e$ be the angle between the two outward pointing normals of the two faces of $P$ attached to $e$. 
  The cylindrical fragment is the "cartesian product" of a line segment of length $\ell_e$ and a circular arc of length $\theta_e \epsilon$. Since $H = \frac{1}{2\epsilon}$ on such a fragment, each edge contribute 
  $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{(\psi_e \epsilon) \ell_e}{2\epsilon}\right) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \ell_e\psi_e$$ to  RHS of $(*1)$.
- $F$ planar polygons, one for each face.

  These planar polygons contributes nothing to RHS of $(*1)$.

Canceling the $2\epsilon$ from both sides of $(*1)$ for $\mathcal{B} = P_\epsilon$,
we obtain

$$\bbox[4pt,border:1px solid blue]{
b(P) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\sum_{e \in \text{edges}(P)} \ell_e \psi_e}
\tag{*2}
$$

Apply these to tetrahedron $\Delta_0$ and notice

- The $4$ outward pointing normals of $\Delta_0$ are $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$, $(0,0,-1)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$.
- The $3$ edges attached to $\vec{0}$ has length $1$. For each of these edges,
  the two faces attached to the edge is perpendicular to each other. ie. $\psi = \frac{\pi}{2}$.
- For the remaining $3$ edges, they have length $\sqrt{2}$. All of them are attached to that face which is an equilateral triangle and having an outward normal 
  pointing in the direction $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$. This implies the corresponding $\psi = \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.

Combine this, we have

$$\begin{align}
b(\Delta) = b(\Delta_0) 
&= \frac{3}{4\pi}\left[ \frac{\pi}{2} + \sqrt{2}\cos^{-1}\left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right)\right]\\
&\approx 1.1131274948822501384717878345303502990597\dots
\end{align}
$$
Same answer as before but in a slightly different analytical form.

Comment: A fantastic answer to a not-so-promising question!

Comment: Thank you so much for this useful answer. You helped a lot for me. :)